# MKStoreKit not working due to new UUID uniqueidentifier change from May 1st (Automatic Reference Counting / Private API)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uuid, uniqueidentifier, mkstorekit

I already answered this question for myself, but it took me a few hours of research, so I wanted to spread the info around.

The APP store changed its requirements on May 1st, 2013, and now no longer allows UUID/Unique Identifier code, and after successfully compiling and archiving, a submission to the store using code that worked just fine last month is now returning an error about Automatic Reference Counting, and advises you update your SDKs and don't use private API's.

As someone who's fairly new to this whole app thing, I had no idea what any of this meant, or what of my code was causing this error.  While searching for these keywords in my code, I found several references in several places.  In my case, the error was coming from my use of the MKStoreKit.

The solution was to delete the VerificationController.m and VerificationController.h files.  This doesn't seem to have had any impact on the store, and it seems like these files were not being used at all.

Comment: use OpenUDID (google it) instead of deviceIdentifier